# Identity managment software over the Active Directory

Tags: caching, active-directory

I want to write a software for managing Windows Active Directory so we can use non-tech people to manage the AD "without knowing it".

1. Do I want to use my AD as a database and run the queries directly on it or is it better to cache the data to a faster database like mongo or something?
2. Does the AD support parallel working? If two users do work on my software, will the AD take care of locks and stuff like oracle?
3. Can the AD callback from events like a write on it or at least can tell me the delta of the operations from my last check or will I need to read all of it each time?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here are the answers:

Q:Do I want to use my AD as a database and run the queries directly on it or is it better to cache the data to a faster database like mongo or something?

A: It depends. Write an app which queries AD directly (like ADUC\ADSI) is much cheaper and faster solution in terms of development than use your own cached database. I recommend to implement it using LDAP API (not ADSI) as ADSI is a wrapper over LDAP.

Q: Does the AD support parallel working? If two users do work on my software, will the AD take care of locks and stuff like oracle?

A: Yes, AD supports parallel working and takes care of locks.

Q: Can the AD callback from events like a write on it or at least can tell me the delta of the operations from my last check or will I need to read all of it each time?

A: There are 3 different [change tracking techniques](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms677625(v=vs.85).aspx). I recommend using DirSync or USNChanged, as Change Notifications is designed to track changes in a small scope, like several users, or groups (not the entire AD).